# Drupal Display Modified Date for Node

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

Is there a simple way in Drupal to display the last modified date for a node as part of the *node.tpl.php* file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you put this code in the node.tpl.php file it will show the date of the last change to the node:

```
<?php
echo format_date($node->changed);
?>
```

with whatever HTML you want around it.

Comment: Thanks!  Seems so simple, but I had a hard time finding it in the documentation...

Answer (score 1):

```
If you place below code in you node.tpl.php file -

<?php 

    $node = node_load($nid);
    echo $node->changed;

?>
```

you will get the timestamp and i think that can be changed to date.

Here $nid in tpl file represent the current node id, and hook node_load() load the all information related to node id.

Comment: I don't think you need to load the node again.  The $node object should be available in node.tpl.php.

Comment: ya i realized that after posting the answer. But thanks to correcting the code performance.

Comment: This doesn't really matter, results of `node_load` are cached so you only incur an extra couple of milliseconds by reloading the node. Depending on the module load order it might actually be *necessary* to reload the node to get at it's fully loaded properties

Comment: This works great in a view header.  I have a view that displays the results of a data table.  I needed to show when the information was last updated. The data table is updated when I upload a new file as an attachment to a specific node.

Answer (score 1):

No need to edit node.tpl.php file. Use the following in template.php.

```
function sitetheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];

  // Only add the revision information if the node is configured to display
  if ($variables['display_submitted'] && ($node->revision_uid != $node->uid || $node->revision_timestamp != $node->created)) {
    // Append the revision information to the submitted by text.
    $revision_account = user_load($node->revision_uid);
    $variables['revision_name'] = theme('username', array('account' => $revision_account));
    $variables['revision_date'] = format_date($node->changed);
    $variables['submitted'] .= t(' and last modified by !revision-name on !revision-date', array(
      '!name' => $variables['name'], '!date' => $variables['date'], '!revision-name' => $variables['revision_name'], '!revision-date' => $variables['revision_date']));
  }
}
```